# --skip-worktree wont let me change branch

Tags: git

I have a local file I needed to change some values do I used:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree myfile.ts
```

This worked but now when I try to change branch I get an error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        myfile.ts
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
```

But I can't stash it as it is ignored?

Is the only solution to set `--no-skip-worktree` then stash it and change branch?  That is pretty inconvenient workflow.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: To save or stash the file (via Git itself), you must clear the skip-worktree bit, yes. You could instead save the file elsewhere (outside this Git repository entirely); that's probably the best course of action in many of these cases.

Answer (score 0):

The `--skip-worktree` option is designed for sparse checkout; it isn't designed to let you modify files without Git knowing about it.  There's no way to modify files that are tracked without Git knowing about it.

If you need to do so, you'll need to be able to stash your changes and restore them.  However, this is, as you implied, a suboptimal workflow.

Typically, if you're trying to modify a config file or such that's checked in, the best approach is to create a template for that file that you check in and then generate the config file using the template.  This lets you specify custom configuration settings in different environments by modifying your template configuration.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "create a template file".  What type of template are you referring to?

Comment: For example, if your config file is in, say, INI format, you can create a file that's called `config.ini.erb` and use Ruby's ERB templating language (or some other templating language) and then generate the `config.ini` file based on the template and an input file.  A primer on doing this is with ERB is available at https://www.stuartellis.name/articles/erb/.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible for me as I am not controlling the code looking for the file.

Comment: Then you'll have to stash or unstash at times when changing branches.  Git doesn't provide a way to ignore changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want git to not care for you changing that I file I think you need to use `git update-index --assume-unchanged`

Comment: This is not accurate.  This works in some cases, but not others, and it can and will break.  This option is designed for slow systems, not to ignore actual changes you've made.